# Java : issue with actionlistener and retrieving textbox input

Tags: java, swing, awt, jbutton, actionlistener

I am working on an assignment in which i need to convert Fahrenheit to Celsius. I have created the form and the actionlistener button.

What I am having problem with is placing the code within the actionlistener to retrieve textbox input and do the calculations and trimming it down to two decimal places and posting the answer in the Celsius textbox.

This is what I have so far:

```
 import java.util.Scanner;
 import javax.swing.*;
 import java.awt.*;
 import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
 import java.awt.event.ActionListener;


 public class Part3Question1 extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

     public static void main(String[] args) {
         JFrame mp = new Part3Question1();
         mp.show();
     }

     public Part3Question1() {
         setTitle("My Farenheit to Celsius Converter");
         setSize(400, 250);
         setLocation(400, 250);
         setVisible(true);
         setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
         setLayout(null);

         JLabel fahrenheitLabel = new JLabel();
         fahrenheitLabel.setText("Fahrenheit: ");
         fahrenheitLabel.setBounds(130, 40, 70, 20);
         add(fahrenheitLabel);

         JTextField fahrenheitTB = new JTextField();
         fahrenheitTB.setHorizontalAlignment(fahrenheitTB.RIGHT);
         fahrenheitTB.setBounds(200, 40, 70, 20);
         add(fahrenheitTB);

         JLabel celsiusLabel = new JLabel();
         celsiusLabel.setText("celsius: ");
         celsiusLabel.setBounds(149, 60, 70, 20);
         add(celsiusLabel);

         Color color = new Color(255, 0, 0);
         JTextField celsiusResultsTB = new JTextField();
         celsiusResultsTB.setText("resultbox ");
         celsiusResultsTB.setHorizontalAlignment(celsiusResultsTB.CENTER);
         celsiusResultsTB.setForeground(color);
         celsiusResultsTB.setEditable(false);
         celsiusResultsTB.setBounds(200, 60, 70, 20);
         add(celsiusResultsTB);

         JButton convertButton = new JButton("Convert");
         convertButton.setBounds(10, 100, 364, 80);
         add(convertButton);

         convertButton.addActionListener(this)
     }

     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
         Part3Question1 convert = new Part3Question1();
         double Farenheit = Double.parseDouble(convert.fahrenheitTB.getText());

         double = Celcius(5.0 / 9.0) * (Farenheit - 32);

         convert.fahrenheitTB.SetText = Celcius;
     }
 }
```

your help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

No, don't create another Part3Question1 object inside of your actionPerformed method:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{   
    Part3Question1 convert = new Part3Question1();
    double Farenheit = Double.parseDouble(convert.fahrenheitTB.getText());
```

Yes, you can create a Part3Question1 object, but understand that it will be completely unrelated to the Part3Question1 object that is currently displayed, which is the current instance, the `this, if you will.

Also, even if your code worked right, this is not how you call a setText(...) method:

```
fahrenheitTB.SetText = Celcius; // you're not even calling a method here!!
```

Instead just call the methods of the current Part3Question1 object that you're in:

```
double farenheit = Double.parseDouble(fahrenheitTB.getText());
```

You can trim the results of the conversion using `String.format("%.2f", someDoubleValue)`, or using DecimalFormat if you prefer this tool.

Comment: so if I understand correctly, my code should look like this?
     
`public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
 { 
  double Farenheit = Double.parseDouble(fahrenheitTB.getText());
  double Celcius = (5.0/9.0)*(Farenheit-32);
  celsiusResultsTB.SetText = Celcius;
 }`

Comment: Again, how do you call a setText ***method***? It's a method, not a variable that you set with the assignment operator, `=`. How do you call methods in general?

Comment: by creating an instance of the object and calling the method. Is that not the correct way?

Comment: unless its a static method, in which a.methodName();

Comment: You call a method by calling it on an instance of an object, but methods need ***parenthesis***. Your setText has none. It makes no sense.

Comment: ok but even when I remove the (), my code still does not work. I am fairly new to this, and this is my first assignment using GUI, so I am a bit confused. I have already completed this assignment using commandline code, and it works fine. But now the second part of the assignment wants me to convert it into a GUI.

Anyhow, I do appreciate your help. Thank you :)

Comment: **Why are you removing the ()**?? You need to ***add*** the (). Again `myTextField.SetText = foobar;` is not the same as `myTextField.setText(foobar)`. See what I'm getting at? Only post code that will compile or else tell us your compilation errors that you're getting. You can't just make this stuff up and expect it to work. Programming isn't like that.

Comment: I'm not making it up. but there is nothing wrong with some trial and error. anyhow. I will keep cracking away at this, and hopefully I find the solution. Thanks for your help though. I do appreciate it.